# Smalltallk - How can I get an Array (or Collection) of the all the Instance variables in an Object (the current Instance) of a Class?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Let's say we have a Class and we instantiate it, creating an Instance of that Class. This Instance has a number of (instance)variables, defined by the class, that I need to use. I'd like to get all these (instance)variables in an Array or some Collection so I can iterate through them and set them to some value, not nil.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is rare to have to access instance variables that way. Are you sure that's what you want, or would you like to provide more context to the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @SeanDeNigris Not really. I'm experimenting with something I developed in Objective-C, trying to get it to work with me in Seaside.

Comment: In Objective-C I couldn't go deeper than the public API so I had to simulate the behavior I want using "surface" available tools. I'm hoping to get this implementation transferred into Smalltalk and then work my way deeper, because of the easy access to the source code. I'll probably ask more vague questions later on, leading on to what I'm doing, but for now I have very specific, weird, ones. Thank you all for looking into them every day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send `#allInstVarNames` to a class (Behavior) to get names of all instance variables defined by it and by superclasses. If you need without superclass variables, you can use `#instVarNames`

Let's say that `var` is your variable that you need to work with. Then you can get the collection of instance variable names and iterate them.

You can use `#instVarNamed:put:` to set instance variable by name, and `#instVarNamed:` to get the value by name (in case you need).

I think that something like this may help you:

```
var class allInstVarNames do: [ :instVarName |
  var instVarNamed: instVarName put: <yourValue>
```

Comment: One more thing... I'm trying to check the initial "value" of one of those instance variables see if it's nil. Tried something like this  "var class instVarNames do: [ :instVarName | instVarName ifNil: [var instVarNamed: instVarName put: <yourvalue>] ] but it doesn't seem to work. What kind of Object is instVarName? Do i need "instVarName value" or something?

Comment: `instVarName` is a string. But you probably wanted to check `(var instVarNamed: instVarName) ifNil: ...`

Comment: @MaxLeske Yes! Figured it out myself when I inspected "var class instVarNames" and composed this: "var class instVarNames do: [ :instVarName | (var instVarNamed: instVarName) ifNil: [var instVarNamed: instVarName put: <yourvalue> ]]"

Answer (score 5):

I would like to build up on @Uko's answer because there is a more direct way to implement his idea.

The message `instSize` sent to a `Class` will answer the number of named instance variables of its instances. This, of course, would include instance variables defined in superclasses.

For instance, `RemoteTempVectorNode instSize` answers with 17 (wow!). Therefore you could do:

```
fields := (1 to: anObject class instSize) collect: [:i | anObject instVarAt: i]
```

and then, change them with:

```
values withIndexDo: [:v :i | anObject instVarAt: i put: v]
```

where `values` is the array of new values you want to inject into the object.

So, why I'm suggesting this instead of `instVarNamed:`? Because the latter is indirect. If you take a look at its implementation you will see that it has to first find out the name of the i-th ivar by sending `instVarIndexFor:ifAbsent:` to the object's class. In other words, if you need the ivar names, follow @Uko's suggestion; otherwise don't bring them into the equation because they will only add CPU cycles to your program.

**One more thing**. As @Sean DeNegris wisely raised in his comment to your question, it would be beneficial if you elaborated a little bit more on why you need such an unusual maneuver.

---

**EDIT:**

Now that Pharo has [Flexible Object Layouts](http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/archives/papers/Verw11a-OOSPLA11-FlexibleObjectLayouts.pdf) the mapping between inst var names and the class `instSize` is no longer valid (in classes that use the new capability.) So, the simpler approach of using just indexes would not work with generality. In fact, under the new "taxonomy" the `instSize` (number of fields) of an object may be different from the `#numberOfInstanceVariables`. I guess that the added flexibility has its costs and benefits.

Comment: I see. Essentially using the name of the instance variables causes a "search" being used to find them, your method uses those indexes directly. This method returns the instance variable of all the super classes of the current class combined. Is there an equivalent of only getting the current classes indexes?

Comment: Exactly. No, there isn't. But you can create it very simply in `Behavior` as `^superclass instSize + 1 to: self instSize`. This method, when added to `Behavior`, will answer with the Interval of indexes corresponding to the receiving `Class` (or `Metaclass`).

Comment: If the "number of fields" "may be different from the numberOfInstanceVariables", what are the extra fields useful for, why do I need to see them?

Comment: You may have, for example, several ivars mapped to the same field in the object's layout. For instance, with the new "flexible layout" you may have several boolean ivars coexisting in the same object field. There are many other possibilities, all of them described with clarity in the paper. In earlier versions of Pharo (and other dialects) every ivar occupies a field. Now, with the reification of ivars that's may no longer be the case. And since `instSize` is a "low level" message, it may not correspond to the `#numberOfInstanceVariables` (all of which is new to me, hence my confusion.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll keep the other answer checked just because it works, but your explanation does put everything in context.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to build on @Uko's answer because the subject was interesting.